# Import a wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Someone gave me a wordpress website (files and sql dump), I imported the database into mysql and the files onto my ftp. 
I modified the site and home url in the option table and opened the website.

The index page is fine but any link I click returns a 404. So I thought about `.htaccess` and tried the default one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But now instead of 404 I have a text like that:

```
Login
mysitename
```

How can I know what's the problem ?

Comment: Please refresh the permalink.. you just have to replace each and every url to the url you wanted to get transfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

- in the template-loader.php file I commented out `do_action( 'template_redirect' );` which solved the 404 error for url like `domain.tld/index.php?page_id=123` but not for formated url like `domain.tld/cat/title`
- as it gave me access to admin I verified the site url in the settings and saved. - I also modified permalink style and saved several times (it didn't work first time)

Now it works

Answer (score 2):

You can open the exported SQL file in an editor and find/replace every instance of the previous URL with the new URL (i.e. `http://www.example2.com` replacing `http://www.example1.com`. Then transfer it again to the server.

In addition you have to edit the server and connection settings in the `wp-config.php file`

ADDITION:

And another thing, an old WP bug which keeps coming: After doing all that just go to the "Permalinks" page in the backend once. Somehow this (i.e. just opening that page) resets the permalinks settings which otherwise sometimes are broken.

Comment: I used a script to rename all old url to new... I can't go to the admin page, only the index works.